Is every bounded connected metric space totally bounded?
A metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be bounded if it is equal to a ball $B(x,r)$ of it. It is said to be totally bounded if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite covering of $X$ by $\epsilon$-balls. Every totally bounded space is a bounded space. For a subset of a Euclidean space they are equivalent, but not in general.
The problem is that the counterexamples that I'm aware of are counterexamples because they are infinite discrete spaces; so a ball small enough can only contain its center. Is every bounded connected metric space then totally bounded?

Take closed unit ball in any infinite-dimensional Banach space.

@MoisheKohan Indeed, thank you so much!

Take $\Bbb R$ with distance $d(x,y)=\min(\lvert x-y\rvert,1)$. The resulting space is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, hence connected, and there is no finite covering by $\frac12$-balls.

@SassatelliGiulio Thank you so much! Right under my nose.
